# method and its variable

Tags: java, android

I want to use the value of `int a` in another class. I have a method to access the `a` variable in another class. I want to use the method to get the value of `a` and use it in my main class.

```
public class Neram {

    private static int a;

    private static void timedel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       for(int i=0;i<20000;i++)
       {
          try {
             Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e){}
          a=a+1;
       }
    }
}
```

I want to use `int a` as a time counter for my other class, then execute code when `a` becomes 100.

All I want is to use a method and get the value of `a, then use it like:

```
if (a > 100) {
    // say time over
   if(a>150)
     // your taking too long
   if(a>200)
  // that s it Stop RIGHT now
}
```

Comment: There are better ways to accomplish this kind of task (incrementing a variable on a timer) - especially because the route you're taking is **not** guaranteed to increment 1 every second (now, it _likely_ will, especially if your thread count is low...).  To properly answer your question, we need to know how you're using `a`/what you're doing with it in your main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly use **TimerTask** or **Handler** for these type of work.. Much more easier for you.

For TimerTask:-
http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html

Fro Handler :- 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-handler-example/

Above are just examples if you dont like try any other examples.

---

Handler handle = new Handler();

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //what ever you want to do...
    }
};
```

//How to call in any method like (onCreate)

handle .postDelayed(runnable , 100);

****Timer Task
public class JavaReminder {
    Timer timer;

```
public JavaReminder(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();  //At this line a new Thread will be created
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000); //delay in milliseconds
}

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("ReminderTask is completed by Java timer");
        timer.cancel(); //Not necessary because we call System.exit
        //System.exit(0); //Stops the AWT thread (and everything else)
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Java timer is about to start");
    JavaReminder reminderBeep = new JavaReminder(5);
    System.out.println("Remindertask is scheduled with Java timer.");
}
```

}

Output
Java timer is about to start
Remindertask is scheduled with Java timer.
ReminderTask is completed by Java timer  //this will print after 5 seconds

Comment: this where i want to add my a value                                                                                       `
                  if(a>10){
                   for (Sprite wave2 : sprites) {
                       wave2.onDraw(canvas);
                       }
                   
                  }  `

Comment: Hi Anu sorry for late reply...I changed the above answer pls check and if your problem is solved by this kindly accept this answer...

Comment: yes i used to time class to create my enemies :) but had a different problem ..my sprites will animate only at that particular time :( .. but thanks to u i learned how to use how to execute things in a particular timing :)

Answer (score 0):

Make "int a" a static member of whichever class you are trying to access it from. Simply use the static keyword to declare it. It's important to understand why this works in Java, though. So I highly suggest you take a quick read on class members and the different access modifiers in Java.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Also, be sure to watch out for synchronization issues if you will be accessing int a from inside another thread.

Comment: If you're going to suggest `static` members, at least suggest one of the atomic wrappers so it'll be threadsafe.  Personally, I'd avoid public mutable static members as much as possible; depending on his use case, having `a` be static might be the wrong suggestion anyways (need more info, though).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Neram {

    public static int a;

    private static void timedel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       for(int i=0;i<20000;i++)
       {
          try {
             Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e){}
          a=a+1;

             if (a>100)
              new Main1 (a);
       }
    }
}
```

import this file to the package with the main class and make the changes..did u want this only or something else?

the Main1 class must have a constructor like

```
Main1(int b)
```

Comment: what if i want to display more when a value keep increasing ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can register a callback method, and share variable value by this callback method between different threads. But for accessing shared variable between threads, you have to synchronize it for protection. such as declare it as volatile, or use AtomicInteger, or create a lock.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a much simpler solution would be to have a `Handler` dispatch a message with some delay amount and then handle your logic instead of having a thread do this...